# Mailchimp: Table columns are different heights. How can I make them all this same?

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email, mailchimp

I was using the Mailchimp template. I need 9 sections with images and text information. I create 9 sections 3x3. I used the option on the template builder where you can use and image and a caption. The captions below the image. It is styled as `<td>`. However, I am having a lot of trouble making sure the heights are all the same so it looks aligned. I can't seem to figure it out. I have messed with the padding, I even added height (didn't have it before) as well as making the `overflow: hidden;` CSS... everything, but each section keeps shifting and the it just doesn't look aligned. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

See the section of my code where I have the first column (generated at first by Mailchimp and then customized by me):

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateColumns">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="columnsContainer" width="33%">
                      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateColumn">
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top" class="leftColumnContainer">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnImageCardBlock">
                              <tbody class="mcnImageCardBlockOuter">
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnImageCardBlockInner" style="padding-top:9px;padding-right:18px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-left:18px;">

                                    <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageCardBottomContent" width="100%" height="100%" overflow="hidden" style="background-color:#2D6C73;">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td class="mcnImageCardBottomImageContent" align="left" style="padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0px;">


                                            <a href="http://teendrive365inschool.com/teens/video-challenge?utm_source=DE&amp;utm_campaign=waystowin&amp;utm_medium=email" title="" target="_blank">

                                              <img alt="Toyota TeenDrive365" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/03342d2b00b6ccea697a3e7e5/images/be1f6169-1a44-4c56-ab24-82a3c96d7eec.jpg" width="164" style="max-width:480px;" class="mcnImage">
                                            </a>

                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding:8px 15px;color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:11px;font-weight:normal;line-height:110%;text-align:center;" width="146" height="80" overflow="hidden;">
                                            <span style="font-size:11px">
                                              <strong>Toyota TeenDrive365 Video Challenge </strong>
                                            </span>
                                          <span style="font-size:10px"><br />
                                          Film a safe driving PSA for&nbsp;a&nbsp;chance at $15,000!</span>
                                          <br>
                                          <span style="font-size:11px"><strong>Challenge Closes February 23</strong></span>
                                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnButtonBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
                              <tbody class="mcnButtonBlockOuter">
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;" valign="top" align="center" class="mcnButtonBlockInner">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="70%" class="mcnButtonContentContainer" style="border-collapse:separate !important;border-top-left-radius:3px;border-top-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px;background-color:#0C4B74;">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="center" valign="center" class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;padding:8px;">
                                            <a class="mcnButton" title="Learn More" href="http://teendrive365inschool.com/teens/video-challenge?utm_source=DE&amp;utm_campaign=waystowin&amp;utm_medium=email" target="_blank" style="font-weight:bold;letter-spacing:normal;line-height:100%;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF;">Learn More</a>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to combine all the tables together into one class and code them together. they were all separate classes. I figured it out. thanks. this can be closed/deleted.